# Clean up Knight Movement method in a chess project with duplicate code

Tags: c++, chess

I am writing a chess [project](https://github.com/wawaroutas/chess) using C++ and SDL. In this method I calculate all available moves a [Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_(chess)) can make and I want to refactor it. I basically move the knight Up/Down 2 squares and then Left/Right 1 square and then do the opposite. As you can see in the 2 for loops the difference is the way `tempPosition.x` and `tempPosition.y` are incremented and then the 2nd loop is the same as the first,but swapped (see comments)

```
std::vector<Position> available;
    Position tempPosition;

    int directions_double[2] = {-2, 2};
    int directions_single[2] = {-1, 1};
  
    for(int double_step : directions_double) {
        tempPosition = position_;
        tempPosition.x += double_step;        // x+=doublestep
        Position temp2_position = tempPosition;
        for(int single : directions_single) {
            tempPosition = temp2_position;
            tempPosition.y += single;          //y+=single step
            if(InBoard(tempPosition))
                available.push_back(tempPosition);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    for(int double_step : directions_double) {
        tempPosition = position_;
        tempPosition.y += double_step;        //y += doublestep
        Position temp2_position = tempPosition;
        for(int single : directions_single) {
            tempPosition = temp2_position;
            tempPosition.x+=single;           //x+= single step
            if(InBoard(tempPosition))
                available.push_back(tempPosition);
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    return available;
}
```

The difference is very small.  I thought of implementing a flag technique, but it didn't seem 'clean' enough.  Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use `Position`s for steps as well

You can avoid the duplication by using `Position`s to represent the steps as well:

```
Position directions_double[] = {{-2, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, -2}, {0, 2}};
...
for (auto double_step: directions_double) {
    ...
    tempPosition.x += double_step.x;
    tempPosition.y += double_step.y;
    ...
}
```

If the type `Position` has [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for `operator+`, then you could simplify the additions to:

```
tempPosition += double_step;
```

For the inner loop, observe that the single steps are just the same as the double steps, but x and y swapped and their values halved:

```
for (auto& double_step: directions_double) {
    ...
    Position single_steps[] = {
        {double_step.y / 2, double_step.x / 2},
        {-double_step.y / 2, -double_step.x / 2},
    };
    for (auto& single: single_steps) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, create one array of steps representing all possible knight moves:

```
Position knight_moves[] = {
    {-2, -1}, {-2,  1},
    {-1, -2}, {-1,  2},
    ...
};
```

With this, the loop becomes even simpler.

## Use consistent naming

You use `double_step` as the value for the outer loop, but `single` for the inner loop. Of course you can't just use `double` as the name of a variable, but you could make it more consistent by writing `single_step`.

## Incorrect `break` statement?

It looks to me like you are trying to check for valid knight moves on a chess board. If so, I think the `break` statement in the inner loops is incorrect.

## Avoid unnecessary temporary variables

The temporary variables currently make the code hard to follow. It would be nice to remove as many of them as possible, and/or give them better names than "temporaryThing". Ideally, the code would look like:

```
Position knight_moves[] = {...};

for (auto& step: knight_moves) {
    auto new_position = position_ + step; 
    if (InBoard(new_position)) {
        available.push_back(new_position);
    }
}
```

This assumes you can add two `Position`s together. If not, you can probably write this instead:

```
Position new_position = {position_.x + step.x, position_.y + step.y};
```

While `new_position` is still a temporary variable, it's the only one, and it has a slightly better name.

Comment: @Sliepen 
Thank you for your input.Best solution I can see is creating one array of Positions and overloading `operator+`.You are correct,this is a chess project me and a friend are working on and this is indeed the `Knight` class. I will definetely take your `naming` input as well since we try to keep things as clean as possible. Any other suggestions you might have before i accept the answer?

Comment: You could make the array `static constexpr`, although a decent compiler will probably generate equally efficient code either way. That's all the suggestions I have.

Comment: Thank you sir,have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Posting the final code using @G. Sliepen input. It turned pretty clean, also used this logic to refactor the rest of the Chess Pieces and the project shrank in lines.

```
//Returns an std::vector<Position> with all available positions a Knight piece
//can attack/move
std::vector<Position>
Knight::AvailableMoves(const std::vector<Material*>& other) const {
  static const int kMovableDirections = 8;
  static const Position moves[kMovableDirections] = {
    {2, 1}, {2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-2, -1}, {1, 2}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {-1, -2}
  };
    std::vector<Position> available;
  for (Position move : moves) {
    Position possible_position = position_ + move;
    if (PositionValid(possible_position, other, color_)) { //Position is valid if in 
      available.push_back(possible_position);              //Board and not occupied 
    }                                                      //by ally piece
  }
  return available;
}
```

Comment: Looks great already. But if you want the new code to be reviewed, I recommend posting it as a new question on this site!

Comment: No thank you man,we are looking good for now. We will work on the Board today. If it turns messy I will ask for opinions again :D

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar things by changing the members (`x` and `y` in your case; `left` and `right` for doing mirror-image on a binary tree without duplicating the code) to be an array of 2 instead.  Then you can have `this_way` and `that_way` set to 0 and 1 in either way, to have the same code work for the transposed case.

`tempPosition.x` becomes `tempPosition.xy[this_way]` and `tempPosition.y` becomes `tempPosition.xy[that_way]`.  The subroutine takes `this_way` as an argument (0 or 1) and generates `that_way` as a local variable `1-this_way`.

Now the two nearly identical blocks of code that differ only in switching the use of `x` and `y` are one function with an additional argument.